# How to increment generator object to execute code after yield in a generator function?

Tags: python, generator

I have a generator function that has some code before yield and some code after yield. Is there a way to skip to the execution of the code after yield without executing the code before yield?

I tried exploring itertools functions but no luck so far.

```py
def func1():
    print("Code before yield is executing")
    yield 
    print("Code after yield is executing")
```

Here I'm trying to write a custom generator that will execute the part after yield and stop.

Comment: On what condition do you only want the code after the yield to run?

Comment: Only iterate once

Comment: I have a different function say, foo() that creates the generator object from this generator function f = func1() and I want this generator object to increment to the code after yield after some external condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

somethin like :

```
def func1(exec = True):
    if exec:
        print("Code before yield is executing")
        yield 
    print("Code after yield is executing")
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to manually consume the generator:

```
gen = func1()
next(gen)
for x in gen:
   # do something with x here
```

Calling `next()` will execute the first element of the generator and ignore it. Then the `for` loop consumes the rest of the generator. Note that this assumes there are no side effects when consuming the first element or that the side effects are still desired.

Comment: Correct, but this will execute the part before yield. I'm looking where I can skip the execution of the part before yield.

Comment: Is there a way to increment the generator without executing the part before yield?

Comment: @Mickstjohn09 No, "incrementing" the generator by definition executes code until a `yield`.

Comment: @Mickstjohn09 This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you want to skip everything before the yield? How are you using the generator and what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a use case where the code before yield has been executed in a different task and I want to execute the code after yield in a different task.

Comment: @Mickstjohn09 What do you mean by "task"? Please edit your question to show a full code example that illustrates the context. Also, I think your current example is not the best because the `print()` calls cause a side effect. Most generators return data instead of having side effects such as this. See my edited answer for a guess at what you might want.

Comment: @Mickstjohn09 If the "tasks" you are talking about are synchronous function calls, it sounds like you need to just pass the generator around so that anyone that needs it can consume elements directly without worrying about what anyone else has done before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196347/discussion-between-mickstjohn09-and-code-apprentice).